# Chaining dependent obsevable and get all values

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to get a user and then his history (this is 2 http GET), and finally i need to get both values, i have a working code :

```
const result: { user?: User } = {};
const user$ = this.userService.getUser(userId);

const history$ = user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => (result.user = user) && this.userService.getHistory(user.historyId)));
    
history$.subscribe((history) => {
  console.log(result.user);
  console.log(history);    
})
```

I read an artcile (https://medium.com/@snorredanielsen/rxjs-accessing-a-previous-value-further-down-the-pipe-chain-b881026701c1) with more elegants options.
If i try the solution 4, the GET user is called twice.

```
const result$ = user$.pipe(
      mergeMap(schema => this.userService.getHistory(user.historyId)),
      withLatestFrom(result$),
      map(([user, history]) => {
          console.log(user);
          console.log(history);
        })
      );

    result$.subscribe();
```

Plus, do you have any other solution ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 4 is a bit strange because `withLatestFrom` creates an additional [subscription](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/25214128ba4427b979dc38ab3fc98006d255d3f2/src/internal/operators/withLatestFrom.ts#L76) on the `user$` stream and if the stream is `cold` meaning that it fires every time a new subscription is made you will have an additional call which is the case you are falling into.

You could use `shareReply` in order to convert the `cold` observable into a hot one (which shares its value with the other subscribers) and use the approach from Solution 4 but I recommend just using the `zip` operator which takes two streams and merges their values into a single stream but make sure that you use zip with `cold` observables in this case, otherwise you will end up with with long loved stream and if you don't destroy it at a certain point you will end up with a memory leak.

```js
const result$ = user$.pipe(
    mergeMap(
        schema => zip([schema], this.userService.getHistory(user.historyId))
    ),
    map(([user, history]) => {
      console.log(user);
      console.log(history);
    })
);

result$.subscribe();
```

Also you can consider using [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) if this action can be performed multiple times after another because if you fall into this case [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) won't cancel the previous calls if they are not done yet and `switchMap` will.

Answer (score 0):

**[withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom)** take the last value from another observable ,
and it will best for your situation

**First**

1- go to **getHistory()** method and inside pipe add **withLatestFrom(user$)**,

2 - replace

```
const result$ = user$.pipe(
      mergeMap(schema => this.userService.getHistory(user.historyId)),
      withLatestFrom(result$),
      map(([user, history]) => {
          console.log(user);
          console.log(history);
        })
      );

    result$.subscribe();
```

to

```
const result$ = this.userService.getHistory(user.historyId).pipe(
      map(([user, history]) => {
          console.log(user);
          console.log(history);
        })
      );
    result$.subscribe();
```

**Second**

if observable fire twice use [**take()**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take) it's rxjs operator that take the first n number of emissions

```
 const result$ = this.userService.getHistory(user.historyId).pipe(
      take(1),
      map(([user, history]) => {
          console.log(user);
          console.log(history);
        })
      );
    result$.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `shareReplay(1)` to avoid making the HTTP request twice like the following:

```
const sharedUser$ = user$.pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

And then use `sharedUser$` instead of `user$` in the chain you mentioned in your question.

However, I think an easier solution for you would be like this:

```
user$.pipe(
  mergeMap(user => this.userService.getHistory(user.historyId).pipe(
    map(history => [ history, user ]),
  )),
  map(([user, history]) => {
    console.log(user);
    console.log(history);
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this:

```
this.userService.getUser(userId).pipe(
  switchMap(user => 
    this.userService.getHistory(user.historyId).pipe(
      map(history => ({user, history}))
    )
  )
).subscribe(({user, history}) => {
  console.log(user);
  console.log(history);
})
```

I think this is fairly idiomatic RxJS. You just build an object with the shape you want and keep passing it forward through the chain of calls. The Subscribe gets the final object. In this case is has the following shape:

```
{
  user: <response from first call>
  history: <response from second call>
}
```